# Full Join tables avoiding duplication

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have two separate tables similar as below:

```
t1
  major     math      biology 
    1       ann        n/a 
    1       n/a        rosa
    2       n/a        tim

t2
  major    english       
    2       elias       
    3       tony
```

My goal is to merge them with the desired output as below (only 1 name per row can be in either math, biology and english):

```
t1 + t2: 
  major     math      biology     english
    1       ann        n/a          n/a
    1       n/a        rosa         n/a
    2       n/a        tim          n/a
    2       n/a        n/a          elias
    3       n/a        n/a          tony
```

I tried to perform FULL JOIN and then COALESCE statement, but it did not work and all the names in t2 are duplicated:

```
SELECT   COALESCE(t1.major, t2.major) AS major, 
         COALESCE(t1.math, 'n/a') AS math, 
         COALESCE(t1.biology, 'n/a') AS biology,
         COALESCE(t2.english, 'n/a') AS english

FROM t1 
FULL JOIN t2 ON t2.major = t1.major
```

I'm still learning SQL so I would greatly appreciate if you could give me a suggestion on how to tackle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal answer to your question appears to be to use `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT major, math, biology, 'n/a' AS english FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT major, 'n/a', 'n/a', english FROM t2
```

The better answer is to point out that your data structure is ***extremely*** problematic.  If you expand on ***why*** your data looks like this, and what you want to do with it, we can point out a much more suitable structure.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. I know the data structure is quite problematic but there can only be 1 value in 1 column and other columns will have null or n/a values and so far that is the structure that I thought of.. Given the example above, everyone is unique and he/she will only appear 1 time (in 1 row and 1 column).

Comment: @tlqn Then you should have two columns; `name, subject`, not one column for each subject.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a UNION, not a JOIN:

```
select major, math, biology, 'n/a'
from t1
union
select major, 'n/a', 'n/a', english
from t2
```

Comment: `UNION` runs de-duplication.  Unless expressly required it should be `UNION ALL` to avoid that (potentially very costly) overhead.